# How to return value in another column where a text 'exact' or 'close' matches text in another google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns to compare against another two columns and return the value in the third column. The challenge is that I need to return an exact match WHERE available otherwise return the closest match EVEN if the match is just one word. So I am looking at a formula that possibly looks at the order of the strings and words maybe where the text is not an exact match.

Here is what I tried but it clearly doesn't get the job done.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(F:F&"*",B:C,2,FALSE))
```

The link to my spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgjFuZItDWW7R1QINKgeSWP2-vvRmkQ2DfwcGXTpfn0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: can you explain why you expect output on `Kenya Anne Egbertrosa` from `Kenya Young Egbert` but not on `Singapore Rosa Weis Gadison` from `Singapore Cyndy Gadison` ?? logic wise it has no sense coz both are partial matches regardless that 2nd one has also the exact match

Comment: From my understanding (correct me if im wrong), if there is an exact match, then you take the value from C, *otherwise* you take the partial match. There is no exact match for Anne Egbertosa, but there is an exact match for Cyndy Gadison, so it ignores Roda Weis Gadison.

Comment: I am basically making sure the person is from the country mentioned. Then that the name is the exact match or close.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've gotten pretty close to what you're looking for. I did use two separate formulas because I was not sure which one would be closer to what you were looking for, so I will explain both.

1:

```
=if(arrayformula(if(B2:B16=F2:F16, "true", "false"))="false", 
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup("*"&G$2:G$16&"*", $B$2:$C$15, 2, false)),
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup("*"&H$2:H$16&"*", $B$2:$C$15, 2, false)),
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup("*"&J$2:J$16&"*", $B$2:$C$15, 2, false)), "x"))), "what")
```

First, I had to split the names into separate cells using `=SPLIT()`. From there, I prioritized first name to last name (If the first name matched, grab that, otherwise if second name matched, grab that, etc). If the formula didn't find any name matches, it returned "x". If the formula ever returns "what", something is wrong.

2:

```
=if(arrayformula(if(B2:B16=F2:F16, "true", "false"))="false", 
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup("*"&G$2:G$16&"*", $B$2:$C$15, 2, false)),
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup("*"&H$2:H$16&"*", $B$2:$C$15, 2, false)),
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup("*"&J$2:J$16&"*", $B$2:$C$15, 2, false)), 
iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(E$2:E$16, $A$2:$C$15, 3, false)), "x")))), "what")
```

For the second formula, I basically did the same thing except at the end of it, if it didn't find any name matches, it matched the country instead.

Using the * at the beginning and end of a string works as a wildcard, [this page probably explains it better than I could.](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/vlookup-wildcard/)

I unfornulately was unable to get it to return an exact match where available, and otherwise return the closest match. It may be a simple solution that I am missing, but I think I got pretty close anyways. If you would want to go as far as to find names inside of names (i.e. Egbert inside of Egbertrosa), that would require splitting the names down by individual letters, which could get messy.

I do see that some of my formula returns different values than the Expected Value, so I will continue to work on that to see if I can fix it.

Here is the link to my spreadsheet because I did need to add 4 columns for the name split, so the structure is slightly different than your current one.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10iMMs1lkJv5QCG2rtJT1BlxVjl79VUZQIoYbelR1gtI/edit?usp=sharing